# Shorting ground and left (or right) of 3.5mm audio jack from the computer

Tags: audio

I'm trying to build a shutter release for my Canon SLR that is controlled from the computer. Since the shutter release is simply shorting two points on the headphone jack together, is there a way to short two pins on the headphone jack together from a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all Canon EOS SLR cameras are able to use the Canon EOS software for semi or complete control from a computer. Heck, you can use your computer as a view screen as well.

Aside from that, a USB GPIO or Relay board will do what you want. You may have to add two transistors for the GPIO board, but that is pretty simple.

There is no standard way of using a headphone jack to short a connection, but there are some hacks that could do so, and some commercial products.

ioShutter is a cable + app combo for iPhones. TriggerTrap and TriggerHappy are similar for Iphones and Android.

`DSLR Remote` is a free app for Android with both commercial and home made cable support. Two of the cables are simple, with [transistors](http://bitshift.bi.funpic.de/en/dslr-remote/hardware/cable-s.php) or [optocouplers](http://bitshift.bi.funpic.de/en/dslr-remote/hardware/cable-a---opto-couplers.php)
As long as the headphone out's maximum volume/output/voltage is high enough, it should trigger the remote. The audio source files arn't included, so the software side you would need to make yourself.

[This site](http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/dslr/canonrelease.html) shows a serial port method for windows, with software. While [this site](http://debianletters.blogspot.com/2007/12/long-time-remote-shooting-with-canon.html) expands on it, with both shutter and focus, with linux software. You could even use a Usb to Serial adaptor with these.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you think any resistance is required for the optocoupler solution? It seems to me it'd just short the phone side/burn the opto's LED. I know we're talking about very low power on the headphone jack, but still... I'm a total noob by the way, I just don't want to accidentally wreck my phone (I know it's not your illustrations, just asking for a best guess)

Answer (score 0):

Not using its soundcard, unless the camera will accept a fairly small pulse instead of a true connection.

Without knowing the details of the camera interface, a USB interfaced relay module should work.  A solid state relay would probably also be an option with slightly more attention to specifications.

If you take time to understand the camera interface, a microcontroller plus transistor/fet or optoisolator solution is likely possible, but you will need to know polarity, voltage, maximum current, etc.

It is also possible the camera has a USB or IR remote interface which could be used.

Comment: I'll try using a USB interface, but any idea how I should connect the pins etc? I tried googling but I think I'm not getting the search terms right.

Comment: If you get a USB relay board, you simply use the relay contacts instead of a pushbutton.